# Style in lightning datatable. Overlap values

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a lightning datatable, and I have a problem. If I edit the bottom column, the values is overlap on the table
Steps: click on editIcon on botton column (OK), click on editIcon on other value of botton column (the value is overlap)

```
<lightning:datatable
    aura:id="objectDataTable"
    columns="{! v.columnsObject }"
    data="{! v.objectList }"
    keyField="Id"
    hideCheckboxColumn="true"
    onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}"
    sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"  
    sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"
    onsave ="{!c.onSave}"
```

The value is overlaping the table
[image]

In standard table, a scroll appear and value not overlap.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try using slds-scrollable class.

Comment: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the **slds-scrollable** property and width and height.

```
<div class="slds-scrollable" style="height: 10rem; width: 50rem;">
            <lightning:datatable data="{!v.mydata}" columns="{!v.mycolumns}" keyField="id" hideCheckboxColumn="true" onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}"
                  sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post: [Lightning Component Height/Width Adjustment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145766/lightning-component-height-width-adjustment)

Creating a dynamic style:

```
<aura:attribute name="divHeight" type="Integer" default="100" />
<div onclick="{!c.changeHeight}" style="{! 'height:'+v.divHeight+'px;'}"></div>
```

In the controller, I controll the number of items:

```
if(numItems > 0){
   var height = 110 + 25 * numItems;
   cmp.set('v.divHeight', height);
}
```